# Do not allow updates on student popularity that result in an average popularity below 70 : error no such column exist

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_avg
before update on student
for each row
BEGIN
SELECT CASE WHEN (avg(popularity)+new.popularity)/2<70
THEN RAISE(ABORT,'Not acceptable popularity , avg goes belown 70') 
end;
end
```

Then i got error when i type :

```
update student
set popularity= 25
where id=5;
```

The following :

> Result: no such column: popularity At line 11: update student set
>   popularity= 25 where id=5;

any ideas? i truly dont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_avg BEFORE UPDATE ON student
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (((SELECT SUM(popularity) FROM student) - OLD.popularity + NEW.popularity) / 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student)) < 70
BEGIN      
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'Not acceptable popularity , avg goes belown 70'); 
END;
```

This checks the new average popularity that would be created if the UPDATE succeded by summing all the existing values in the column `popularity`, subtracting the *old* popularity and adding the *new* one and dividing by the number of rows in the table.